# Place labels between ticks of a slider-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-slider

I have a slider with ticks and ranges that I made using some examples of the [bootstrap-slider documentation](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/), especially [Example 12](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/#example-12), however, I can't put labels between the ticks.

This is my current code, and works like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fS12.jpg)

```js
$(() => {
  $('#sastdastSlider').slider({
    id: 'sastdastSliderContainer',
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    range: true,
    focus: true,
    ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ticks_labels: ['Info', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Critical'],
    lock_to_ticks: true,
  });
});
```

```css
p { margin: 1em 2em !important; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="text" id="sastdastSlider" />
</p>
```

As you can see the labels are under each tick, and I want them to appear in between, like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not a default-possible option. You will have to use CSS to offset them if this is the result you want.

Comment: I migrated your external imgur link to an embedded stack image. Is this the correct image? If so, your labels already appear under the the ticks

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No, that isn't the right image, it was the other

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `margin-left`

```
.slider-tick-label:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -35px; /* px as required */
}
```